# TypeError: props.addToCart is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to dispatch my action when the client clicks the "addToCart" btn. which will add a new product to the cart, but i get the following error: "TypeError: props.addToCart is not a function".
I am quite new to Redux and have learned the basics, but i cant seem to fix this problem.

code cartActions:

```
import * as actions from '../constants/cartConstants'
import store from '../storeRedux'

console.log(store.getState())
//go through all the items and add the item with the specific id
//with getState we can get whatever exists in the redux store
export const addToCart = (product,qty,count) =>(dispatch)=> {
    let exists = false
    const cartItems = store.getState().cart.cartItems.slice()
    cartItems.forEach(item=> {
        if(item.id === product.id){
            exists = true
            item.qty++
            count++
            qty++
            
        }
    })
    if(!exists){
        cartItems.push({...product, count : 1, qty: 1})
    }
    dispatch({
        type: actions.ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {cartItems}
    })
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems))
}

export const removeFromCart = (product)=>(dispatch) =>{
    const cartItems = store.getState()
    .cart.cartItems.slice()
    .filter(
        x => x.id !== product.id
    )
    dispatch({
        type: actions.REMOVE_FROM_CART,
        payload: {cartItems}
    })
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems",JSON.stringify(cartItems))
}

export const adjustQty = (product,qty)=> (dispatch)=> {
    
    
    dispatch({
          type: actions.ADJUST_QTY,
        payload: {
            product,
            qty
        }
    })
  
}



export const reset =(cartItems,qty,count)=> (dispatch)=> {
    dispatch({
        type: actions.RESET,
        payload: {
            cartItems,
            qty,
            count
        }
    })
}
```

Code cartReducer:

```
import * as actions from '../constants/cartConstants'



const initialState = {
    cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [] , 
    count:0, 
    qty: 0,
    amount: 0
}

const shopReducer = (
    state = initialState,action)=> {
    switch(action.type){
        case actions.ADD_TO_CART:
            return{
                ...state,
                cartItems:action.payload.cartItems,
                count: action.payload.count,
                qty: action.payload.qty
               
            }
        case actions.REMOVE_FROM_CART:
            return  {
                ...state,
                cartItems:action.payload.cartItems,
                count: action.payload.count
                     }
               
        case actions.RESET:
            return{
                ...state,
                cartItems: action.payload.cartItems =[],
                qty: action.payload.qty =0,
                count: action.payload.count =0,
                amount: action.payload.amount =0
            }
        
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default shopReducer
```

Code productPage:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import '../styles/productdetails.css'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { detailsProduct } from '../../actions/productActions'
import Review from '../components/review'
import { addToCart } from '../../actions/CartActions'




function ProductPage(props){

    //manage quantity product
    const productDetails = useSelector(state=> state.productDetails)
    const{product,loading,error} = productDetails
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const cart = useSelector(state=> state.cart)
    const {qty} = cart
    
    

    useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(detailsProduct(props.match.params.id))
    }, [])
 
  
 
  






  
   
  
    return(
    
        <div>
            <Nav/>
            <a className="product-a" href="/store">Back to products</a>
       
            
    {loading? <div>loading...</div>: error? <div>{error}</div>: 
    (
        <div className="productpage">
         <div className="img" style={{background: `url(${product.img})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}></div>
         <div className="description">
         <h1>{product.name}</h1>
         <p>{product.description}</p>
         <span><small>€</small>{product.price}</span>
 
        <div className="amount">
         <p>Number:</p>  
        <label>
        <button type="button" className="btnInc" onClick={()=> {}}>+</button>
        <input type="number"step="1" min="1" value={qty} />    
        <button type='button' className="btnDec" onClick={()=> {}}>-</button>
        </label> 
        <div>Size: {product.size}</div>
         </div>
    
        {product.qty > 0? <button type="submit" className="addBtn" onClick={()=> {props.addToCart(product)}}> Add to cart</button> : <div>Out of stock</div>}
         
         </div>
 
         </div>
    
       

    
        
    )}
    <Review/>
    <div className="reviews">
        <h3>username</h3>
        <p>reviews : 3 out of 5</p>
        <p>description of what he says</p>
    </div>
</div>  
    )
}




export default connect(null,addToCart)(ProductPage)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `props.addToCart`? You're importing that action at the top, so try just `addToCart(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
export default connect(null,{addToCart})(ProductPage)
```

According to the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object) the mapDispatchToProps parameter can either be a function or an object (or undefined).

If it is a function then it is expected to [return an object](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#returns-1) and each property of that object is expected to be a function that can be called by your component to dispatch an action.

If it is an [object](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form) then each property of that that object should be a function that returns an action (action creator). Connect will replace that function with a function that will pass arguments to the action creator and dispatches the resulting action.

So `{addToCart}` is shorthand for: `{addToCart: addToCart}` which is an object with an `addTocart` property that has a value of the action creator named `addToCart`.

Comment: Thank you! so you need to put the redux actions between "{}" when connecting with your component, right ?